# is there any reasonable number of subviews?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uiview

I want to create something similiar to EMD Periodic Table application. I'm wondering how they did this animation when first creen appears. There is over 50 rectangles and they appear with animation. Does it make sense to add 50 subviews and manage them separately? Is it proper way to achieve this effect?

itunes.apple.com/us/app/emd-pte/id377393859?mt=8

-- 
Piotr

Answer (score 2):

They could be Core Animation layers rather than full-on views.

Answer (score 0):

Try it and see :) It should be OK with just UIViews but there might be an issue on older phones with framerate.

Failing that, openGL would be the way forward - have a look at cocos2d (http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) which makes accelerated 2d work pretty easy.

Though if you really want the perspective effect, you will probably have to go all the way into openGL proper.